# Implementing a write back fifo cache in C

Tags: c, caching, struct, fifo

I am trying to implement a fifo cache into a C program.  I have a struct:

```
struct cache{

int blockid;
int used;
char content[SIZE];
};
```

I made an array of pointers,

```
struct cache **buffer[size];
```

And after allocating this cache with the amount of blocks specified, I am having troubles finding the cache entry that stores the block id given (void *get_cache_block(int id) and returning the cached block.  I am not sure how to iterate through my array of pointer.
Also inserting a new entry into the cache is a function which I am in need of help!

Thanks ahead for the help.

Comment: why are you using double pointer?

Comment: can you explain how do you insert elements into the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have shown, you are allocating an array of pointers to pointers, not pointers to structs, the declaration of your cache should be `struct cache *buffer[size]`. Finding a cache with a given id is a simple for loop, the gist of which is:

```
int i;
struct cache *cur;

for (i = 0, cur = buffer[0]; i < size; cur = buffer[++i]) {
    if (cur->blockid == id) {
        break;
    }
}

if (i < size) return cur;
else return 0;
```

The function get_cache_block should return a `struct cache *` instead of a `void *` because a void pointer indicates an unknown type.

Additionally, you'll probably want to use a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for caching, as it has the nice property of overwriting the oldest entry in the buffer when the cache is full. Hopefully that helps and good luck.